# Set Ehcache's persistence directory programmatically on Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, ehcache, jcache

I'm setting my caches programmatically on Spring Boot and I need to set the persistence directory.

According to [Ehcache's documentation](https://www.ehcache.org/documentation/3.8/107.html), this must be done globally at the *CachingProvider* level:

```
CachingProvider cachingProvider = Caching.getCachingProvider();
EhcacheCachingProvider ehcacheProvider = (EhcacheCachingProvider) cachingProvider; 

DefaultConfiguration configuration = new DefaultConfiguration(ehcacheProvider.getDefaultClassLoader(),
  new DefaultPersistenceConfiguration(getPersistenceDirectory())); 

CacheManager cacheManager = ehcacheProvider.getCacheManager(ehcacheProvider.getDefaultURI(), configuration);
```

The problem is, the mechanism offered by Spring to configure caches, [JCacheManagerCustomizer](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/cache/JCacheManagerCustomizer.html), works at the *CacheManager* level, by then it's too late to set the persistence directory.

So, my question is, what is the best way to achieve this? I do not want to use *ehcache.xml* to do this, I inject a bunch of configurations on my application and [it's support of dynamic configuration](https://github.com/ehcache/ehcache3/issues/1429) is too limited to my needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So at the moment, before someone points me to the right direction, what I'm doing is:

```
...
import org.springframework.cache.CacheManager;
import org.springframework.cache.jcache.JCacheCacheManager;
...
@Configuration
@EnableCaching
public class CacheConfiguration {
...
@Bean
    public CacheManager getCacheManager() {
        var cachingProvider = (EhcacheCachingProvider) Caching.getCachingProvider();

        DefaultConfiguration configuration = new DefaultConfiguration(cachingProvider.getDefaultClassLoader(),
                new DefaultPersistenceConfiguration(directory.toFile()));

        var cacheManager = cachingProvider.getCacheManager(cachingProvider.getDefaultURI(), configuration);
        cacheManager.createCache(...)
        return new JCacheCacheManager(cacheManager);
    }
...
}
```

I feel this is not quite right, it seems I'm bypassing Spring by getting a reference to the *CachingProvider*. I mean, Spring detects the Ehcache provider on the classpath, shouldn't it inject the *CachingProvider* for me?